# Drupal Notifications module - how to obtain a subscription id (SID)?

Tags: drupal, notifications, subscription

I want to show a subscribe/unsubscribe link on a forum topic list page, along with each of the topics in the list. I have all the info for the subscribe link in the $topic variable in mytheme_preprocess_forum_topic_list():

```
foreach ($variables['topics'] as $id => $topic) {
```

Assuming that I want to call notifications_get_link() to get the unsubscribe link, how can I obtain the subscription id (SID) for any existing subscription for the topic node?

I suppose I ought to call notifications_user_get_subscriptions(), but the documentation is a bit thin. An example would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution finds exactly one subscription for the current node if one exists and composes either a susbcribe or unsubscribe link that is made available to the template:

```
// find subscription
$subs = notifications_user_get_subscriptions(
        $user->uid,
        'node',
        $topic->nid, 
        $topic,     
        FALSE);

// compose link
$destination = "?destination=forum/idea-exchange";
if ($subs) {
   foreach ($subs as $key => $sub) {
      $link = notifications_get_link('unsubscribe', array(
              'sid' => $sub->sid, 
              'confirm' => FALSE));
      $variables['topics'][$id]->subscribe_link = 
         '<a class="unsubscribe" href="/'.$link['href'].
               $destination.'">'.t('Stop tracking this topic').'</a>';
      break;
   }
}
else {
  $link = notifications_get_link(
        'subscribe', 
        array('uid' => $user->uid, 
              'type' => 'thread', 
              'fields' => array('nid' => $topic->nid), 
              'confirm' => FALSE));
  $variables['topics'][$id]->subscribe_link = 
      '<a class="subscribe" href="/'.
       $link['href'].$destination.'">'.t('Track this topic').'</a>';
}
```

I ended up using a CCK Computed Field for this so that I can include it in a View. See [this](http://drupal.org/node/937842) for more context.